# Broken output view from WSL terminal with Docker & Laravel

Tags: php, terminal, phpstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

when i doing commands in terminal i got outputs looking like this:

[image]

As you can see, the problem is that the terminal does not display successive lines of the result from the beginning of the line, only from the place where the previously displayed line ends.

It is very uncomfortable to use today. The problem happens on the WSL console with the `php artisan` commands which I have to use because I have a project created with **Laravel** on **Windows 11** using **Windows Subsystem for Linux**, **Ubuntu** and **Docker**.

How i can fix this?

**UPDATE**

The same happens when I use WSL **outside of the IDE** (PHPStorm), from the Windows directly in Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: Just to confirm, does it happen apart from the IDE with the same command in a Windows WSL shell?

Comment: @duck_in_hat yes